# Use mutually exclusive logging context in NestJs | Node JS

Tags: node.js, typescript, logging, nestjs, winston

I am building an application using NestJs and trying to have a logger that can add some meta-data in logger when the request is received and keep on appending it with every log but only during the flow of the original request, the other requests should not interfere with this, in short, the logging context should be mutually exclusive. I tried doing this with winston but could not really make much progress. Please help if there is a lib or practice that can help achieve this.,

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, i would try doing something like this: make logging service that initially creates a winston logger and namespace as requestId, provide methods for changing namespace's requestId and from there provide logginService to middleware and then middleware to module or AppModule in general.

But generally i think you are looking for cls-hooked npm package, if you create namespace for logging service with it it will ensure that request context is unique.